# Transformar uma lista em várias dentro da mesma

Tags: python, lista

Eu tenho a seguinte lista:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Quero que fique assim:

```
X = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
```

Comment: Para que você obtenha respostas melhores é melhor que você coloque aqui o que já fez, como está seu código, onde está dando erro... Não só o que você quer fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Basta iterares a lista e encapsulares cada um dos elementos num array.

exemplo:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4, 40]
novalista = []
for x in lista:
    novalista.append([x])

print(novalista)
```

`novalista` irá conter o resultado desejado.

**[veja a funcionar no onlinegdb.com](https://onlinegdb.com/HyXZCCJpE)**

Comment: Se o valor de `lista` for diferente, como `lista = [1,2,3,40]`, isto não funciona. Não entendi o por quê do `novalista.append([lista[x-1]])` e não apenas `novalista.append([x])`. Poderia me explicar?

Comment: Realmente o `lista[x-1]` não fez sentido algum e por isso deixei meu voto negativo. Se for corrigir a resposta, poderei rever meu voto.

Comment: pequeno colapso, mas já esta corrigido!

Answer (score 1):

Com list comprehension basta fazer:

`nova_lista = [[i] for i in X]`

Usando `numpy`, podemos mudar a forma do `array`:

```
import numpy

X = [1,2,3,4,5]
nova_lista = numpy.array(X).reshape(len(X),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom...aqui eu tenho uma lista em que os valores dentro dela são mutáveis, ou seja, a medida que o sistema evolui, ele automaticamente vai mudando. Ex: Meses do ano, onde posso ter uma lista que começa em dezembro, e está em maio(dias atuais). Essa lista então seria assim:

```
meses = [12,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Com a lista sendo assim, resolvi tranquilamente com a sugestão de correção do colega AlexCiuffa.

```
X = []

for x in months_list_number:

  X.append([x])
```

Dessa forma então o resultado obtido na print foi:

[[12],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]

Comment: Então por que não utilizar (e aceitar) a resposta dele? Não vejo motivos para não utilizar a compreensão de lista nesse caso.